# Mcrypt Extention required error in Bitnami MAMP stack

Tags: php, macos, mamp, bitnami, php-5.6

I am using Bitnami MAMP Stack 5.6.34. And installed it as root user so it loads at port 80. I am trying to install laravel 4.2 using composer and it shows that:

```
Mcrypt PHP extension required error.
```

and also while I try to use

```
php artisan
```

it does not work. Mcrypt is installed as it shows Enabled while I output phpinfo() function. But it still does not show up when I try using

```
php -m | grep mcrypt
```

I have modified php.ini file as follows:

```
mcrypt.algorithms_dir= /Applications/mampstack/common/lib/libmcrypt
mcrypt.modes_dir= /Applications/mampstack/common/lib/libmcrypt
```

But it does not work and still shows:
    Mcrypt PHP extension required error.
But when I cd into mampstack and then use

```
sudo ./use_mampstack
```

then in the terminal I don't get any error while using composer install and can also use php artisan command as it finds that Mcrypt is enabled. 
How can I get rid the Mcrypt error and load it with installed php

Comment: Note, the mcrypt extension was deprecated in PHP 7.1 and removed in 7.2 -- you probably do not want to develop any new software that requires it.

Comment: I actually am working on an old software so to update that I had to go back to PHP 5.6. I'll update the software to PHP 7.2 as I work on it.

Answer (score 0):

Bitnami Engineer here. I just installed Laravel in a fresh Bitnami installation in Mac OS X. These are the steps I followed

```
cd installdir/frameworks
curl -LO "https://github.com/laravel/laravel/archive/v4.2.11.zip"
unzip v4.2.11.zip
mv laravel-4.2.11 laravel
cd laravel
composer install
php artisan --version
```

Then, configure Apache using the similar config files (httpd-prefix.conf and httpd-app.conf) than the other frameworks or the ones at `installdir/docs/demo`. You will only need to modify the different paths in those files and include the httpd-prefix.conf file in the `installdir/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami-apps-prefix.conf` file. Restart Apache at the end to load this configuration.

I hope this helps